# Change color for only specific assets in Adobe XD

Tags: color, adobe-xd

Let's say one is designing an app and there are two assets, a navigation bar and a tab bar, on multiple screens, that happen to initially use the color Black.

I have watched several instructional videos that explain how in Adobe XD one can change the color by, say, adding the Black color as a color asset and then editing said color asset.

But, let's say one only wants to change the color asset Black on the navigation bar assets only? So far, when I change the color in the color asset, XD indiscriminately changes the color of ANY asset that happens to have that color.